# ipset behave differently when adding IP address from iptables and ipset command

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall, centos7

I have a list that created below command

```
ipset create foo hash:ip maxelem 40000000 timeout 180
```

This is how empty foo look like

```
#ipset list foo
Name: foo
Type: hash:ip
Revision: 1
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 40000000 timeout 180
Size in memory: 16504
References: 0
Members:
```

Then I added a /16 subnet which means 65535 IP addresses. As we can see below commands, hashsize changed dynamically and IP addresses added succesfully.

```
#ipset add foo 192.168.0.0/16


#ipset list foo | head -10
Name: foo
Type: hash:ip
Revision: 1
Header: family inet hashsize 32768 maxelem 40000000 timeout 180
Size in memory: 2925208
References: 0
Members:
192.168.165.92 timeout 175
192.168.241.240 timeout 175
192.168.84.49 timeout 175

# ipset list foo | wc -l
65543
```

Now I am destroying this set and creating again with same command above so that I equalize hashsize to 1024 again. Then I added below rule to iptables and sending random packages with hping3

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t raw -j SET --add-set foo src

hping3  --flood  --rand-source <server-ip>
```

While attack continues, it looks iptables can not add more IP addresses after some point. And hashsize stays same

```
# ipset list foo |  wc -l
12295

# ipset list foo |  head -10
Name: foo
Type: hash:ip
Revision: 1
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 40000000 timeout 180
Size in memory: 262264
References: 1
Members:
5.125.171.17 timeout 174
92.5.220.202 timeout 174
164.124.160.24 timeout 174
```

If I repeat this test by increasing hashsize by hand, it makes iptables can add more IP addresses.

I did this test on CentOS 7 with below versions

```
kernel 3.15.9
ipset 6.19
iptables 1.4.21
```

My question is that what is the reason of this cituation? Is this a security precaution or something?

Comment: If you are going to add subnets then create the set using type hash:net instead of hash:ip. You'll save some memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *it looks like `iptables` can not add more IP addresses after some point*

That is expected behaviour for an `ipset` hashtable as described in the [manual](http://ipset.netfilter.org/ipset.man.html) in the Introduction:

> ... When entries added by the SET target of iptables/ip6tables, then **the hash size is fixed** and the set won't be duplicated, even if the new entry cannot be added to the set.

No reason is given, but one might speculate that preventing a firewall from potentially claiming an unlimited amount of memory  is a Good Thing<sup>TM</sup> ....